# Processing Concurrent Future - Multi Processing is slower than Synchronous Approach in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I want to process a list of 1 million documents in Python Concurrent Future. But I see it consumes lot of time than a normal synchronous approach. Below is the sample code snippet with detail.

**Code to create a list of dictionary**

```
data = []

for i in range(1, 1000000):
    data.append({"_id":i, "name":"MaxPayne "+str(i)})
```

**Helper function to print text**

```
def printText(d):
    return d
```

**Synchronous way**

```
for i in data:
    x=printText(i["name"])
    print(x)

Sychronous way takes 8 seconds to process entire list and print the data
```

**Concurrent Future Processpool**

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
     results = [executor.submit(printText, d["name"]) for d in data]

     for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
         print(f.result())

Concurrent Future way takes 300 seconds to process entire list and print the data
```

May I know what is the issue. Can any one help me fixing this bug. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Good question, you may want to make the title clearer to indicate that your issue is that concurrent is slower than synchronous

Comment: @jabberwocky ya changed :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python multiprocessing seems slower than regular execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53555224/python-multiprocessing-seems-slower-than-regular-execution)

Comment: It takes some time to transfer the input data to the process pool and to transfer the results back. Multiplied by one million it's noticable.

Comment: did you try with async?
that acceptable for you?

Comment: I think the bulk of the time comes from printing, not the other code (which does nothing but return the same value), so I would use a different example that times the result of a function that actually operates on the data to get a realistic comparison.

Comment: I reckon printing to stdout is limited by the terminal IO speed. In the sync case, the for loop is already bottlenecked by the printing speed and not by CPU. So no point in using parallel processing. The overhead of data passing between processes will slow it down even more. That being said, I have a feeling that async_map might be a bit faster, although still slower than single-threaded.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer  ya thank you for the link.

Comment: @BenyGj Nope will have to try

Comment: @EricTruett Hmm okay

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi okay you think async_map will solve my problem ??